# Flutter Local Notifications Proguard Rules.pro file has unresolved class members?

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, proguard

I have a flutter app using Flutter Local Notifications package 4.0.0. I have followed the setup as per the documentation, and getting ready for release build I have added the proguard-rules.pro as it says to do. However, this proguard-rules.pro file shows the gson rules (that am being told to include, by local notifications package) these rules are all showing errors as unresolved member classes. Is this correct or do I need to do something else as well? Thank you all